Can I have a legend for a data point as well as a legend for a grouped barplot in one graph
clustered barplot
I have added a legend to show the bars in a barplot, but I cannot figure out how to add the data point (+) to the legend. I want the data points that are + to be labeled in the legend as REF
The script I have used is:
CBC11 <- ggplot(NULL) +
geom_bar(data=Long, width=0.6, position = position_dodge(width=0.6), stat="identity", aes(fill=source, y=mgPCU, x=Herd)) +
theme_bw() + theme(legend.title = element_text(size=18),
legend.text = element_text(size=20))+ scale_fill_hue() +
theme(axis.text.x =element_blank())+ theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 16)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,87), expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.1))) +
labs(fill=NULL) + theme(legend.position = "right") + labs(x = "Herds", y = "mg/PCU") +
theme(axis.title = element_text(size=18)) +
geom_point(data=ref, aes(x=Herd, y=REF), shape=3, cex=4)
